# In continuous variables why should I expect that $p_y(y) =p_x(g^{−1}(y))$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

In a chapter about continuous variables in a [textbook (p.69)](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/prob.html) I read that

> [A] technical detail of continuous variables relates to handling continuous random variables that are deterministic functions of one another. Suppose we have two random variables,$x$ and $y$, such that $y=g(x)$, where $g$ is an invertible, continuous, differentiable transformation. One might expect that $p_y(y) =p_x(g^{−1}(y))$.This is actually not the case.
> <sub>*Deep Learning*, chapter 3, page 69, by Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio, Aaron Courville</sub>

I don't understand why I should have expected that $p_y(y) =p_x(g^{−1}(y))$. Indeed, I don't understand that part $p_x(g^{−1}(y))$?

I understand that $p_x$ is a the probability distribution function. But why would the one of $g(x) $ be its inverse?

I am a slow learner in mathematics. Don't hesitate to explain it to me as if I was a teenager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have expected $p_y(y) = p_X(g^{-1}(x))$ due to how probability distributions behave in the discrete case.

Let $X\in\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ be a discrete random variable, for which you know the probability distribution $p_X(X)$ (the probability for each $x_i, i=1,2,\dots$).

Now, you have $Y=g(X)$ for invertible $g(\bullet)$. What are the possible values $Y$ can take? The answer is to apply $g$ to all possible values for $X$: $g(x_1),g(x_2),\dots$ or equivalently $y_1,y_2,\dots$ with $y_i:=g(x_i), i=1,2,\dots$.

Now, if you know the probability that $X=x_i$ occurs, what is the probability that $Y=y_i=g(x_i)$ occurs? Since the event $Y=g(x_i)$ depends on a single $X=x_i$ (since $g$ is invertible), the probability is the same. Hence, $P(Y=g(x_i)) = p_X(x_i)$.

You may want to write this in terms of $y_i$'s only. Since $g$ is invertible $x_i = g^{-1}(y_i)$ so that:
$$
p_Y(y_i) = P(Y=y_i) = P(Y=g(x_i))= p_X(x_i) = p_X(g^{-1}(y_i))
$$
In conclusion: $p_Y(Y) = p_X(g^{-1}(Y)) $.

This reasoning works well in the discrete case. That is why one might expect this to translate to continuous case. However, in continuous time you have to work with probability densities instead. The idea is very similar, and the correct formula introduces an extra factor to correct for the change of variables, when computing the probability as an integral (acting as a Jacobian). See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar).